# Reset button in differents Browsers

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I configured a button to refresh the web page when we click on it. This allows me to reset the values entered in my inputs. On Google chrome and Internet Explorer it works perfectly. But on Mozilla Firefox, the web page refreshes itself but keeps the parameters of my inputs. Do you know why ?

```
    # ui.R

jsResetCode <- "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"

useShinyjs(),
extendShinyjs(text = jsResetCode),
actionButton("reset_button", "Refresh")


    # server.R

observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    js$reset()
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to provide a full reproducible example next time. Here's some sample code highlighting your problem that can be run as-is:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = "shinyjs.reset = function() {history.go(0)}"),
  textInput("test", "test", "test"),
  actionButton("reset_button", "Refresh")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$reset_button, {
    shinyjs::js$reset()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

There are two possible solutions:

1. If you just want to reset all the inputs on the page, you can use `shinyjs::reset()`
2. If you actually want to refresh the page and also have the inputs reset, I believe you should use `window.location.reload(true)` instead of `history.go(0)`